# rospy.wait_for_message is unable to subscribe to a message

Tags: ros, rospy, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rospy.wait_for_message](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message) can receive one message from topic. It will create a new subscription to the topic, receive one message, then unsubscribe. But when I try to use it, the function can't work at all. For example,

```
roscore &
rostopic pub -r 1 /data std_msgs/Float32 2.0
```

the use this function to subscribe once:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
rospy.wait_for_message('/data', Float32)
```

It will be stuck here and there is no response at all. But if we subscribe directly

```
rostopic echo /data
```

It can work. What's the matter with this function? And I try to test it on different computers and ROS version, the result is the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312996/rospy.wait_for_message-is-unable-to-subscribe-to-a-message/) by [Liulong Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/39506/liulong-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just add

```
rospy.init_node('test')
```

before.

---

Originally posted by [Liulong Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/39506/liulong-ma/) with karma: 23 on 2019-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-17**:
That's one of [the first calls that you make](https://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Initializing_your_ROS_Node)